# Leaflet.draw retrieve layer type on draw:edited event

Tags: leaflet

I'm using the https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw plugin and I'm trying to retrieve the layer type of an edited layer.

On the `draw:created` event, I have the `layer` and `layerType`, but on `draw:edited` (triggered when saving all edits) I get a list of layers that were edited.

The **[draw:created](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#drawcreated)** event

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'marker') {
        // Do marker specific actions
    }

    // Do whatever else you need to. (save to db, add to map etc)
    map.addLayer(layer);
});
```

The **[draw:edited](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#drawedited)** event

```
map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
    var layers = e.layers;
    layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        //do stuff, but I can't check which type I'm working with
        // the layer parameter doesn't mention its type
    });
});
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use `instanceof` [(docs here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

```js
map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
    var layers = e.layers;
    layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (layer instanceof L.Marker){
            //Do marker specific actions here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 30):

Be very careful when using `instanceof`. [`Leaflet.draw` plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) uses standard [Leaflet's L.Rectangle](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#rectangle). Leaflet's rectangle extends [Polygon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon). Polygon extends [Polyline](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline). Therefore, some shapes might give you unexpected results using this method.

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

... add layers to drawnItems ...

// Iterate through the layers    
drawnItems.eachLayer(function(layer) {

    if (layer instanceof L.Rectangle) {
        console.log('im an instance of L rectangle');
    }

    if (layer instanceof L.Polygon) {
        console.log('im an instance of L polygon');
    }

    if (layer instanceof L.Polyline) {
        console.log('im an instance of L polyline');
    }

});
```

## How do i find out the shape type?

```
var getShapeType = function(layer) {

    if (layer instanceof L.Circle) {
        return 'circle';
    }

    if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
        return 'marker';
    }

    if ((layer instanceof L.Polyline) && ! (layer instanceof L.Polygon)) {
        return 'polyline';
    }

    if ((layer instanceof L.Polygon) && ! (layer instanceof L.Rectangle)) {
        return 'polygon';
    }

    if (layer instanceof L.Rectangle) {
        return 'rectangle';
    }

};
```

Comment: Shouldn't be better to invert order? test Rectangle --> return , test Polygon --> return, test Polyline --> return

Comment: Thank you mate !! Was stuck, wondering why my Polyline was found as a Polygon.. I understand now why! Thanksssssssss