# How to edit a popup in Leaflet.draw

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, leaflet.draw

I am using Leaflet and Leaflet.draw to create a map.  When I draw a rectangle on the map (as a user), the following code writes out the LatLng bounds of the rectangle.

```
    // add the newly drawn items to a layer
    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;

        // binds things upon creation
        if (type === 'rectangle') {
            var bounds = layer.getBounds();
            layer.bindPopup(bounds.getNorthWest().toString() + "NW" + bounds.getSouthEast().toString() + "SE");
        }

        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    });
```

I want to update this when the rectangle is edited by the user.  I think that something like this should be updated using the 'draw:edited' event and '_popup.SetContent', but the LatLng in the  does not update.

```
    // update LatLng when edited
    map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;

        // update popup
        if (type === 'rectangle') {
            var bounds = layer.getBounds();
            layer._popup.SetContent(bounds.getNorthWest().toString() + "NW" + bounds.getSouthEast().toString() + "SE");
        }
    });
```

Adding that second code block also means that I can only edit the first rectangle ever created.  So it's clearly not working, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  For the [draw:edited](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#drawedited) event, I needed to use the [eachLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-stuff-methods) method to iterate through each layer in `e.layers`, and then `instanceof` to check the layer type.  I also bound a new popup instead of editing the old popup.

Here's the code, which also has a line break in the popup to make it more readable:

```
    // update LatLng value
    map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
        var layers = e.layers;

        layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            // do whatever you want to each layer, here update LatLng
            if (layer instanceof L.Rectangle) {
                var bounds = layer.getBounds();
                layer.bindPopup(bounds.getNorthWest().toString() +  " NW<br>" + bounds.getSouthEast().toString() + " SE");
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks to [this question about retrieving layer type on edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014907/leaflet-draw-retrieve-layer-type-on-drawedited-event) for pointing me in the right direction.