# How do I get a Leaflet shape's layer type when clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

My Leaflet project allows the users to draw shapes (lines, rectangles and polygons). The user can click on the shapes to get their statistics (area, perimeter, etc).

I tried a click event on my FeatureGroup(), where all the shapes I have drawn is added. I am not sure if this is the best approach. Then upon click, a function taking an event is called. The layer type is inferred from the event object.

```
 //Handlers for when drawn shapes are clicked
        editableLayers.on('click', onLayerClick);

        function onLayerClick(e)
        {
            let type = e.layerType,
                layer = e.layer;
            if (type === 'polygon') {
                polygons.push(e.layer);
                let area = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer.getLatLngs()[0]);
                console.log("New polygon area: " + area);
            }

            if (type === 'rectangle') {
                rectangles.push(e.layer);
                let area = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer.getLatLngs()[0]);
                console.log("New rectangle area: " + area);
            }     
        }
```

The type object returns an undefined, and the layer object returns a bunch of parameters making no reference to the shape type. Because of that, I cannot infer the shape type and perform the correct calculations to get their stats.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but contains useful info... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014907/leaflet-draw-retrieve-layer-type-on-drawedited-event

Answer (score 4):

I would leverage the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) for this task, e.g.:

```
function onLayerClick(ev) {
  var targetLayer = ev.sourceTarget;
  if (targetLayer instanceof L.Rectangle) {
     // Do something
  } else if (targetLayer instanceof L.Polygon) {
     // Do something
  } else if (targetLayer instanceof L.Polyline) {
     // Do something
  } else {
     // Do something
  }
}
```

Note that due to [how inheritance works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance), any instance of `L.Rectangle` is also an instance of `L.Polygon`, and `L.Polyline` and `L.Path` - that's why the code should check first for the most specific subclasses.

Remember to check out the Leaflet reference, specifically for the bits which tell you about the inheritance tree, [e.g.](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#rectangle):

> ### Rectangle
>
> A class for drawing rectangle overlays on a map. Extends Polygon.

The [Leaflet class diagram](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/class-diagram.html) is also useful for understanding the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that `event.layerType` is a special property added by Leaflet.draw plugin, only when a new feature has been created by a user.

When you attach your click event listener on Leaflet standard Feature Group, the click event object does not have such layerType property, as you can check on the [docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html).

As for a solution, see IvanSanchez's answer.